# When I change size of plugin video player in wordpress foundation it has scroll on the bottom

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I want to change the default size of plugin video player in wordpress foundation it has scroll on the bottom that make my website look not friendly. so please help me to solve this problem.

Note: I need size 907px because it match with my website size. if i change it to small than this it can work and no scroll but it not good.

Here is my picture of size:
[click here to see my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fFeq.png) |
[click here to see photo change size in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWJ0c.png)

Comment: everyone who can respond my question?

Comment: No we can't. You need to provide the markup generated for the video and the associated css.

Answer (score -1):

Just go in your core file and change the size it's very simple

```
    <?php 
       image_resize( $file, $max_w, $max_h, $crop, $suffix, $dest_path,  
       $jpeg_quality ); 
    ?>
```